# TortoiseGitの設定のウィンドウの幅を広げる方法が知りたい

Tags: tortoisegit

TortoiseGitの設定のウィンドウ幅が狭く表示され、右側の情報が表示されない状態で見ることができません。
ウィンドウを右クリックしても「移動」と「閉じる」しか表示されないので拡大する方法がありません。
OSはWindows 10 Pro(64bit バージョン21H1)です。
よろしくお願いします。

Comment: Windowsのスタートボタンから、TortoiseGit＞Settingsで右クリックで「管理者として実行」を選んだ場合は通常の広い幅で表示されます。

Comment: 再インストールでもダメでしたか？

Comment: 問題発生時の画面イメージと、念のため TortoiseGit のバージョン情報も質問煮含めておくと回答が付きやすいかもしれません。

Comment: @Itagaki さん
再インストールでrepairを利用したら正常に動作するようになりました。
ありがとうございます。

Comment: @cubick さん
ありがとうございます。
バージョンは、2.13.0.1でした。